# How to edit gallery images more view slider in product page?

Tags: magento2

My custom theme extend form magento-black. I had try edit gallery images slider in product page. but I can't change number items to show and slider working not correct with items carousel is normal.

I had found code in file

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

I saw code js

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
        "mage/gallery/gallery": {
            "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
            "magnifierOpts": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getMagnifier(); ?>,
            "data": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getGalleryImagesJson(); ?>,
            "options": {
                "nav": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/nav"); ?>",
                "loop": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/loop"); ?>,
                "keyboard": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/keyboard"); ?>,
                "arrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/arrows"); ?>,
                "allowfullscreen": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/allowfullscreen"); ?>,
                "showCaption": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/caption"); ?>,
                "width": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>,
                "thumbwidth": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width'); ?>,
                "thumbheight": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height')
                    ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width'); ?>,
                "height": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height')
                    ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>,
                "transitionduration": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/transition/duration"); ?>,
                "transition": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/transition/effect"); ?>",
                "navarrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/navarrows"); ?>,
                "navtype": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/navtype"); ?>",
                "navdir": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/navdir"); ?>"
            },
            "fullscreen": {
                "nav": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/nav"); ?>",
                "loop": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/loop"); ?>,
                "navdir": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navdir"); ?>",
                "arrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/arrows"); ?>,
                "showCaption": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption"); ?>,
                "transitionduration": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/duration"); ?>,
                "transition": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/effect"); ?>"
            },
            "breakpoints": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getBreakpoints(); ?>
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't edit with our requirments
Below is design. Please help me change to correct design.
Thanks a lot.
[image]

Comment: How many items you want to show in more view slider. Send me link for website.Currently in 4 showing in screenshot .

Comment: Thank you for interesting!
There are 4 items in slider. I have fixed it by try override "gallery.phtml" and set owlcarousel.

Comment: Thanks, yes owlcarousel  is best script for custom slider .

Comment: Please share the code to achieve it

Comment: @Mr Tim, Did you solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't directly change it. Because in Magento 2, jQuery gallery fotorama (Fotorama 4.6.4) is used to create an image gallery.

If you need to change the design you must override the fotoram script (`lib/web/fotorama/fotorama.js`) or you can override the `gallery.phtml` on your theme.

```
json_decode($block->getGalleryImagesJson());
```

will give all gallery images that you needed. you can use any other `jQuery` gallery or image slider on your theme

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. I will try it.
Sorry for I don't vote, because I'm new member.

Comment: Is it Possible to show more than one slide at a time ??

Answer (score 3):

Vars located in `theme_folder/etc/view.xml` or in `module_name/etc/view.xml`

For luma theme it's `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml`

Answer (score 2):

You can place the file `view.xml` in your theme's `/etc` directory with contents like this:

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="product_page_image_small" type="thumbnail">
                <width>90</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

By changing the width and height of the images, you can control how many will be displayed in the slider.

Comment: I want to apply thumbnail slider in magento 1 in fotorama. How can i apply it? please help me

Answer (score 2):

To customize fotorama options which are listed here: http://fotorama.io/customize/options/

Just add additional params in magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

Of course don't edit vendor files but override it with your theme or custom extension.

Example of setting custom margin for navigation slides: ("thumbmargin":30)

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
        "mage/gallery/gallery": {
            "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
            "magnifierOpts": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getMagnifier(); ?>,
            "data": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getGalleryImagesJson(); ?>,
            "options": {
                "thumbmargin":30,
                "nav": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/nav"); ?>",
                <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/loop"))): ?>
                    "loop": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/loop"); ?>,
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/keyboard"))): ?>
                    "keyboard": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/keyboard"); ?>,
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/arrows"))): ?>
                    "arrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/arrows"); ?>,
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/allowfullscreen"))): ?>
                    "allowfullscreen": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/allowfullscreen"); ?>,
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/caption"))): ?>
                    "showCaption": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/caption"); ?>,
                <?php endif; ?>
                "width": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>",
                "thumbwidth": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width'); ?>",
                <?php if ($block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height') || $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width')): ?>
                    "thumbheight": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height')
                    ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width'); ?>,
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height') || $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width')): ?>
                    "height": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height')
                    ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>,
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/transition/duration")): ?>
                    "transitionduration": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/transition/duration"); ?>,
                <?php endif; ?>
                "transition": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/transition/effect"); ?>",
                <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/navarrows"))): ?>
                    "navarrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/navarrows"); ?>,
                <?php endif; ?>
                "navtype": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/navtype"); ?>",
                "navdir": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/navdir"); ?>"
            },
            "fullscreen": {
                "nav": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/nav"); ?>",
                <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/loop")): ?>
                    "loop": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/loop"); ?>,
                <?php endif; ?>
                "navdir": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navdir"); ?>",
                <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/transition/navarrows")): ?>
                    "navarrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navarrows"); ?>,
                <?php endif; ?>
                "navtype": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navtype"); ?>",
                <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/arrows")): ?>
                    "arrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/arrows"); ?>,
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption")): ?>
                    "showCaption": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption"); ?>,
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/duration")): ?>
                    "transitionduration": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/duration"); ?>,
                <?php endif; ?>
                "transition": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/effect"); ?>"
            },
            "breakpoints": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getBreakpoints(); ?>
        }
    }
}
```

This is also possible by setting global js variable:

```
<script>
  fotoramaDefaults = {
    thumbmargin: 30,
  }
</script>
```

but remember that this variable needs to be set before fotorama gallery initialization.

Answer (score 0):

**"number items to show"**
you can't change number of items in carousel, number of items depends of the gallery width.
You can try to change width of carousel.

**"Slider working not correct with items carousel is normal"**
Please, report issue about it.

Answer (score 0):

http://fotorama.io/customize/

http://fotorama.io/customize/options/

You can use this link for customization Fotorama gallery. Magento2 using Fotorama gallery at product page.