# How to Display 5 images by default in magento 2 product gallery vertical

Tags: magento2, catalog, gallery, gallery-image

I need to show by default 5 images in magento prduct page gallery.
I change the view of gallery is from vertical to horizontal.
I need to know that which js file i have to modify for display default 5 images in product galley.
Please specify any way by which i can display 5 images default in product galley page.

My view.xml galley code

```
<!-- Gallery and magnifier theme settings. Start -->
        <var name="gallery">
            <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Gallery navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
            <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Gallery navigation loop (true/false) -->
            <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false) -->
            <var name="arrows">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false) -->
            <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
            <var name="allowfullscreen">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
            <var name="navdir">vertical</var> <!-- Sliding direction of thumbnails (horizontal/vertical) -->
            <var name="navarrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off on the thumbs navigation sides (true/false) -->
            <var name="navtype">slides</var> <!-- Sliding type of thumbnails (slides/thumbs) -->
            <var name="transition">
                <var name="effect">slide</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
                <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
            </var>
            <var name="fullscreen">
                <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
                <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation loop (true/false/null) -->
                <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false/null) -->
                <var name="arrows">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false/null) -->
                <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
                <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!--Sliding direction of thumbnails in full screen(horizontal/vertical)  -->
                <var name="thumbwidth">50</var> <!-- Width of thumbnails in fullscreen -->
                <var name="thumbheight">50</var> <!-- Height of thumbnails in fullscreen -->
                <var name="navigation_carousel">true</var> <!-- Display navigation thumbs as carousel (true/false) -->
                <var name="transition">
                    <var name="effect">dissolve</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
                    <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
                    <var name="carousel">true</var> <!-- Display navigation thumbs as carousel (true/false) -->
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>
```

Gallery.phtml setting.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
                "magnifierOpts": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getMagnifier(); ?>,
                "data": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getGalleryImagesJson(); ?>,
                "options": {
                    "nav": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/nav"); ?>",
                    "loop": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/loop"); ?>,
                    "keyboard": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/keyboard"); ?>,
                    "arrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/arrows"); ?>,
                    "allowfullscreen": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/allowfullscreen"); ?>,
                    "showCaption": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/caption"); ?>,
                    "width": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>,
                    "thumbwidth": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width'); ?>,
                    "thumbheight": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height')
                        ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width'); ?>,
                    "height": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height')
                        ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>,
                    "transitionduration": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/transition/duration"); ?>,
                    "transition": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/transition/effect"); ?>",
                    "navarrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/navarrows"); ?>,
                    "navtype": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/navtype"); ?>",
                    "navdir": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/navdir"); ?>"
                },
                "fullscreen": {
                    "nav": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/nav"); ?>",
                    "loop": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/loop"); ?>,
                    "navdir": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navdir"); ?>",
                    "arrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/arrows"); ?>,
                    "showCaption": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption"); ?>,
                    "transitionduration": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/duration"); ?>,
                    "transition": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/effect"); ?>"
                },
                "breakpoints": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getBreakpoints(); ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the file view.xml in your theme's /etc directory with contents like this:

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="product_page_image_small" type="thumbnail">
                <width>68</width>
                <height>80</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

One more thing product images in gallery will come as per your product galley container.
If you want to more image in your gallery without arrow navigation..then observe height of your product gallery container then resize image as per that.
Like if Container height is 350 then

```
<width>68</width>
<height>70</height>
```

source : [How to edit gallery images more view slider in product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96092/how-to-edit-gallery-images-more-view-slider-in-product-page)

Answer (score -2):

Please try to update the value to 5 for "**Products per Page on Grid Default Value**" under catalog=>Storefront from the admin panel.

Comment: this is not a category listing page